# Do perfect polynomials of degree $4$ exist?

Tags: polynomials, roots, integers

I asked this question already, but I cannot find it anymore. If it is a duplicate,
 I will delete it.

Is there a polynomial

$$p(x)=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$

such that p and all the derivates upto the third all have the maximal possible number
of simple integer roots.

In other words, the polynomials can be written as follows :

$p(x)=(x-e)(x-f)(x-g)(x-h)$ with distinct integers $e,f,g,h$

$p'(x)=4(x-i)(x-j)(x-k)$ with distinct integers $i,j,k$

$p''(x)=12(x-l)(x-m)$ with distinct integers $l,m$

and finally

$p'''(x)=24(x-n)$ with integer n.

I conjecture that no such polynomial exists, but I have no idea how to prove it.
I call such polynomials perfect polynomials ( Hopefully, there is no other meaning for perfect polynomials, otherwise "ideal polynomials" might work). There are perfect polynomials of degree 3.

Comment: You should not abuse notation by using $f$ twice like that. Maybe rename your polynomial $p(x)$ or something.

Comment: Show some examples of degree 3

Comment: $x^3 - 24x^2 + 45x + 950$ is an example for a perfect polynomial of degree 3.

Comment: $x^3 - 3x^2 - 144x - 140$ is another one.

Comment: A short note, since this seems to be a form which leads to simple computations. Unfortunately the Polynomial cannot have the form $P(x)=(x-a)(x+a)(x-b)(x+b)$. In this case $P'=X(4X^2-c)$ and $P''=12X^2-c$. It is impossible for both $\frac{c}{4}$ and $\frac{c}{12}$ to be perfect squares.... So the polynomial cannot have a line of symmetry :(

Comment: Another short note: Since the desired property is invariant under translation by integers, we can assume that $n = 0$. Working backwards from $p'''$, the first non-obvious thing is whether we can have $x^2 + xy + y^2 = 3z^2$ for integers $x\neq y$ and $z$.

Comment: @DanielFischer There are many such; for example $(x,y) = (6,33)$, $(13,46)$, $(23,71)$, ...

Comment: I tried to find a polynomial with brute force and it seems that the lowest and the highest root must have a great difference, something like $3\ 000$, if I remember right.

Comment: @rogerl Good. Then we have candidates for $p'$. The next step would be to see if any of them leads to an eligible $p$. I'm too lazy to even write down what conditions that yields. Are you interested?

Comment: @DanielFischer Just to record that is your expression is  equivalent to $(2x+y)^2+3y^2=12z^2$ in case this helps.

Comment: @DanielFischer Can you explain how you got to this condition? (Perhaps a partial answer would now be more appropriate than continuing a comment stream?)

Comment: @rogerl You start with $p'''(x) = 24x$, which yields $p''(x) = 12x^2+\alpha$, the condition for integer roots then gives $p''(x) = 12 (x-k)(x+k) = 12 (x^2-k^2)$. Then $p'(x) = 4x^3 -12k^2 +\alpha$, the roots again must sum to $0$, so $p'(x) = 4 (x-i)(x-j)(x+i+j)$. Multiply and equate coefficients.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yeah, I just worked that out as well.

Comment: @DanielFischer Integrating $p'(x)$ gives $x^4 - 6k^2x^2 + \alpha x + \beta$, so that (in the notation of the OP) $e+f+g+h = 0$ and $ef + eg + eh + fg + fh + gh = -6k^2$. Substituting and simplifying gives $e^2 + f^2 + g^2 + ef + eg + fg = 6k^2$. This has no solutions for $0\le e, f, g\le 200$. To check higher values of $e$, $f$, $g$ requires a smarter algorithm or a faster computer.

Comment: @rogerl Is a solution to that last equation in three distinct integers a sufficient condition to find (or disprove) the existence of such a polynomial?

Comment: @NotNotLogical No, it's not. By the way, my statement that there are no solutions for small $e$, $f$, $g$ is wrong. There are many solutions (there are 69 such triples for all three less than $100$). For example, $(e,f,g) = (3,7,31)$ gives an expression equal to $6\cdot 15^2$. But the polynomial $(x-3)(x-7)(x-31)(x+41)$ has derivative $4(x^3-675x+3230)$, and this cubic is irreducible.

Comment: @rogerl I see, thank you.

Comment: @NotNotLogical And the condition for when it *is* reducible seems pretty complicated, and I've confused myself multiple times trying to figure it out. But if my Mathematica program is correct, of all the solutions for $0\le e<f<g\le 300$, the only ones whose derivatives factor are $(e,f,g) = (3,31,283)$, where $p'(x) = 4(x+221)(x^2-221x+3454)$ and $(e,f,g) = (37,109,213)$, where $p'(x) = 4(x-70)(x^2+70x-41975)$.

Comment: $n=4a$, so you don't have to worry about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is open: http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/quartic_rationally_derived_polynomials

From looking at a few of the relevant papers, this appears to be an extremely difficult problem.  For example, the full classification of cubics with this property required the theory of elliptic curves.

Note that if we allow two of the roots of $p$ to coincide, examples do exist, such as $X^2(X-308)(X-360)$.  According to a paper of Buchholz and Kelly, equivalence classes of such polynomials are parametrized by a certain elliptic curve.

Comment: Amazing! I did not find anything about this problem for years although it obviously has been studied.

Comment: Do you know how big the difference of the roots has to be, if an example exists ?

Comment: I don't.  But there is a full classification of cubics with this property, and a full classification of quartics $p$ such that $p$ and $p'$ have distinct integer roots.  So it should be possible to narrow down the search quite a lot, and get very large lower bounds.